# Flutter gradient bottom line in ios (Home indicator in ios)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to remove or change color of that gradient bottom line and remove margin of bottom nav bar. There is no any problem with displaying layout in android. How to fix it? Here is my code:

```dart
 Widget _buildContent(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        bool handle = !await widget._screenStates[_pressedPosition].currentState
            .maybePop();
        if (handle) {
          return await _showExitDialog(context);
        } else {
          return handle;
        }
      },
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: <Widget>[
            PageView(
              physics: new NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _pageController,
              children: _mainScreens(),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: CurvedNavigationBar(
                animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                onTap: (int position) {
                  _bottomTapped(position);
                },
                height: BottomAppBarHeight,
                items: <Widget>[
                  ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage('assets/images/logo_small.png'),
                    color: PrimaryColor,
                    size: 40.0,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.list,
                    size: 25.0,
                    color: (_pressedPosition == 1)
                        ? PrimaryColor
                        : DarkerGreyColor,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.shopping_cart,
                    size: 25.0,
                    color: (_pressedPosition == 2)
                        ? PrimaryColor
                        : DarkerGreyColor,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.favorite,
                    size: 25.0,
                    color: (_pressedPosition == 3)
                        ? PrimaryColor
                        : DarkerGreyColor,
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.account_circle,
                    size: 25.0,
                    color: (_pressedPosition == 4)
                        ? PrimaryColor
                        : DarkerGreyColor,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Thanks for your help! In addition, here is image with bottom gradient line:

[image: Example image]

I think that problem is in the safe area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try `fit:StackFit.loose`,

or

```
SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child: myWidgetThatFillsTheScreen,
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to try it))

Comment: @shorol   Hey, could you help me out here? Would be very nice :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65901751/white-bottombar-only-on-the-new-ios-version.