# White bottombar only on the new ios version

Tags: ios, flutter

Does anyone know how to get rid of the white bottom bar(aka home indicator) (see picture). It appears only on IOS 14 devices and more specific on devices without a homebutton. Thanks.[image]

Edited: It appears only when a bottombar is implemented.

```
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [Colors.deepPurple[400], Colors.deepPurple[700]]),
        ),
        height: getBottomBarSize(),
        child: getText(),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50916769/flutter-fullscreen-app-getting-rid-of-the-blank-white-space-at-the-bottom-of-th) helps

Comment: @Elfor thanks I tried, but it doesn't really work. After calling SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUiOverlays([]) only the black bar disappers but the white thing still exists.

Comment: `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUiOverlays([])` is what caused the white space for the guy asking.
did you try the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50917464/12571630)
(set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` to `false` on `Scaffold`)?

Comment: @Elfor yes I tried this, but it didn't work. Seems to be a issue with the bottomAppBar. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution, somehow the BottomAppBar is the problem, following snippet works for me.(Changing BottomAppBar to SafeArea and set bootom:false)

```
    bottomNavigationBar: SafeArea(
      bottom: false,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
              colors: [Colors.deepPurple[400], Colors.deepPurple[700]]),
        ),
        height: getBottomBarSize(),
        child: getText(),
      ),
    ),
```