# How do I remove the white area from BottomAppBar Flutter IOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this bottomAppBar problem in Flutter on an Iphone. I don't know why but there is this white area on the bottom and when I change the theme of the app, it didn't change with it (only when I put this bottomAppBar) Does someone know how to fix that ? Thanks

[image: Iphone Image]

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
            child: 
              Container(
              
              color: Color.fromRGBO(10, 10, 10, 1),
              
              height: 60,
              child: Row(
                
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            currentScreen = Fy();
                            currentTab = 0;
                          });
                        },
                        iconSize: 40,
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
                        color: currentTab == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                        ),

                        

                      MaterialButton(

                      
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            currentScreen = const Search();
                            currentTab = 1;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              size: 40,
                              color: currentTab == 1 ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey,
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]
                  ),
                  
                ],
              
            
              ),
            
          )
      ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I encountered this problem yesterday. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65911153/15703329) solved my problem

Comment: Thanks it was the safe area + bottom false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a `SafeArea` widget somewhere up the tree from your bottom navigation bar? If so, set the `bottom` property of it to `false`. This will make you UI build right to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: @Boatti Awesome!! An upvote would be appreciated it if helped :)

Comment: Just wrapping Scaffold with SafeArea worked for me.